# See useragent in an https connection?

Tags: https, wireshark

I have an app, and it makes an https connection to a server. Is it possible to use something like wireshark or charlesproxy to just see the useragent that it's connecting with? I don't want to see any of the actual data, just the useragent - but I'm not sure if that is encrypted as well? (and if it's worth trying)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to...

No. Browser first establishes secure connection with server, then use it for transfer all data including requests' data, various headers etc.

Comment: Are you sure about that? How comes I can see the headers sent when I inspect a website in Chrome? Isn't it the same thing?

Comment: Absolutely sure. You can see all that info because inside a browser or inside a http server the data is unencrypted, otherwise it is not possible to handle the data. But outside the browser or server (outside the secure connection) you cannot inspect any data. Ok?

Answer (score 0):

Too late for the original inquirer, but the answer is that it may be possible in some cases, depending on application implementation. 
You can use fiddler, and by turning on the 'decrypt https traffic' you also have visibility to the HTTPS content in some cases.
What fiddler does (on windows at least) is register itself within the wininet as system proxy. It can also add certificates (requires your approval when you select to decrypt https traffic) and generates on the fly certificates for the accessed domains, thus being MitM.
Applications using this infrastructure will be 'exposed' to this MitM. I ran fiddler and ran a few applications and was able to view https traffic related to office products (winword, powerpoint, outlook) other MS executables (Searchprotocolhost.exe) but also to some non-microsoft products such as apple software update, cisco jabber)